Supabase - referring primary & foreign key row is always null
I have a profiles table and a subscriptions table that has the primary key of profile_id that references the id of profiles as a foreign key.
Profiles:

Subscriptions:



As you can see below the profile id in subscriptions matches the id of profile. However when I try to select the subscription I always get null.
 const { data: profile, error: profileError } = await supabaseAdmin
    .from("profiles")
    .select(
      `*,
       subscriptions!profile_id(
        *
      )
    `
    )
    .eq("user_id", user.id)
    .single();

I've also tried referrencing the foreign key directly without luck.
 const { data: profile, error: profileError } = await supabaseAdmin
    .from("profiles")
    .select(
      `*,
       subscriptions!subscriptions_profile_id_fkey(
        *
      )
    `
    )
    .eq("user_id", user.id)
    .single();

Any suggestions on how to get the subscription would be greatly appreciated!

I figured it out, had to do with RLS policy.
